# PHP Templating in Laravel 4

Tags: php, templates, laravel, laravel-4

I just did a fresh install of laravel 4.1. I am not really a big fan of templating languages so I would just prefer to use regular php for the templating. However, I do like the idea of inheritance and sections that laravel provides. I have seen examples of using the sections like so:

```
<?php Section::start('content'); ?>
    Test Content
<?php Section::stop(); ?>
```

However, when I try this on my install I am getting:

```
Class 'Section' not found
```

When I try doing it with the blade templates it works fine but not with a regular php template. I cannot find any documentation at all about just regular php templates, all I can find is documentation on blade. Is this not available in the new version or has it changed? Any links or help would be greatly appreciated as googling keeps coming up with results for how to use blade templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `View` actually `Illuminate/View/Environment.php`:

```
<!-- layuts/mastrer.php -->

<body>
    <?php echo View::yieldContent('content'); ?>
</body>

<!-- views/home/index.php -->

<?php View::startSection('content'); ?>

    <?php echo 'Welcome ' . $name; ?>

<?php View::stopSection(); ?>
```

**BaseController class:**

```
protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

protected function setupLayout()
{
    if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
    {
        $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
    }
}
```

**HomeController class:**

```
public function ShowHome()
    $this->layout->title = 'Laravel -> Lout';
    $this->layout->content = View::make('home.index', ['name' => 'Sheikh Heera']);
}
```

But, if you use these functions then why not just use the `blade` ?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was able to get it working now, however the only thing that I was not able to figure out was extending a layout within a view. Ex. with blade it would be @extends('layous.default') but looking through that class it doesn't seem like it supports it with the php engine. I see you can do it in the controller but I would much rather control that in the templates. And I didn't want to use blade because I would rather keep my templates separated. If I were to go to another framework I could keep the templates and just send the data where with blade I might not be able to.

Comment: That is not possible at all :-)